# Oracle WebLogic Plug-in on Eclipse cannot connect to WebLogic Domains

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, weblogic

I 'm working on a Java EE project that uses the legacy oracle weblogic version (10.3.5). I've stalled the latest version of the eclipse Weblog plugin and managed to create domains and start a new service instance. The issue is that eclipse successfully starts the service instance, but does not connect to weblogic domains. In view of this, I'm struggling to manage to debug my application. Attached is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Error creating JMX connector
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJMXHelper.connectToJMX(WlsJMXHelper.java:123)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJMXHelper.getDomainObject(WlsJMXHelper.java:191)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.validateRemote(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:1480)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.validateRemote(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:2715)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.ServerWatcher.runOnce(ServerWatcher.java:600)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.ServerWatcher.run(ServerWatcher.java:495)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Error creating JMX connector
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJMXHelper.createConnector(WlsJMXHelper.java:482)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJMXHelper.connectToJMX(WlsJMXHelper.java:107)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class weblogic.jndi.Environment
    at weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory.getInitialContext(WLInitialContextFactory.java:117)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:730)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:305)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:236)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:208)
    at weblogic.management.remote.common.ClientProviderBase.makeConnection(ClientProviderBase.java:178)
    at weblogic.management.remote.common.ClientProviderBase.newJMXConnector(ClientProviderBase.java:84)
    at java.management/javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.newJMXConnector(JMXConnectorFactory.java:378)
    at java.management/javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:269)
    at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJMXHelper.createConnector(WlsJMXHelper.java:455)
    ... 7 more
```

As far as I know, the root of this is `java.lang. NoClassDefFoundError: could not initialize weblogic.jndi.Environment` class. However, I can't figure out how to deal with it. I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: can you post the error message and the stack trace from the server log (not the output) where you may find the root cause of of NoClassDefFoudError.
Did you create a domain in dev mode with only an admin server ?